# Create a instance in sub-model from User model using Django social auth

Tags: django, django-socialauth

I am using django social auth for social network login into my site and it works fine the user info is stored in the **User** model. But i have another model(**ExtraInfo**) that inherits the **user** model to store extra data. How do i create an new instance in the sub-model(**ExtraInfo**) when a new user is created in the User model by django social auth

I tried SOCIAL_AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.CustomUser' but this does not work since create_user method is not available for the sub-model

```
class ExtraInfo(User):
      phoneNo = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
      city = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
      state = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Django docs, the recommended way to add attributes for a `User` is to use `OneToOneField` instead of subclassing like:

```
class ExtraInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='extra_info')
    phoneNo = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
```

As for your problem, you can connect to Django's `post_save` signal ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save)) and then whenever `created` parameter will be `True`, then create an `ExtraInfo` model for that new user.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your project, but it looks like your `ExtraInfo` model shouldn't inherit from `User` model but instead extend it as mentioned by @miki725, or by using [django profiles](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#auth-profiles).

Regarding django-social-auth, you can extend the default [pipeline](http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pipeline.html) with a function that creates the needed `ExtraInfo` model (you can check if the user is new with the `is_new` argument).

If users are created by other means, then signal is the way to go.